# scrapy often got stuck at "Starting new HTTPS connection" and can't move on

Tags: web-crawler

I was trying to use scrapy-redis to crawl webpages as many as possible. But the spider often got stuck when "DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection" and can't move on. If i close this process and reopen another one, the spider can still perform correctly until the issue occurs again. Please help me. THANKS.
The log is posted below.

2022-11-29 10:29:37 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): learn.microsoft.com:443
2022-11-29 10:29:38 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://learn.microsoft.com:443 "GET /es-es/dotnet/api/system.drawing.configuration.systemdrawingsection.bitmapsuffix?view=netframework-4.8 HTTP/1.1" 200 10906
2022-11-29 10:29:38 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com:443
2022-11-29 10:29:40 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com:443 "GET /t5/workfront-questions/linking-connecting-projects/m-p/472753/highlight/true HTTP/1.1" 200 40251
2022-11-29 10:29:40 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com:443
2022-11-29 10:30:13 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com:443 "GET /t5/workfront-questions/linking-connecting-projects/m-p/472752/highlight/true HTTP/1.1" 200 40239
2022-11-29 10:30:14 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): learn.microsoft.com:443
2022-11-29 10:30:15 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://learn.microsoft.com:443 "GET /es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 10895
2022-11-29 10:30:15 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): learn.microsoft.com:443
2022-11-29 10:30:15 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://learn.microsoft.com:443 "GET /zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.drawing.configuration.systemdrawingsection.bitmapsuffix?view=netframework-4.8 HTTP/1.1" 200 11248
2022-11-29 10:30:15 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): learn.microsoft.com:443

I expect the spider to crawl continuously.